# Adding and removing tracks from a Spotify playlist app

Tags: reactjs, logic

I'm currently completing a project where I have to build a Spotify playlist creator.  For part of this, I need to add or remove tracks from the playlist.  I've coded a method that appears to work, but it is different from the official solution, so I just want to see whether there is a reason I shouldn't do it my way.

Specifically, they use .find and .filter methods where I have used .includes.  Is there a downside to what I've done?

**Their code**

```
addTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    if (tracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id === track.id)) {
      return;
    }

    tracks.push(track);
    this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks});
}

removeTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    tracks = tracks.filter(currentTrack => currentTrack.id !== track.id);

    this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
}
```

**My code**

```
addTrack(track) {
   let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
   if (!tracks.includes(track)) {
      tracks.push(track);
   }
   this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
}

removeTrack(track) {
   let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
   if (tracks.includes(track)) {
     let index = tracks.indexOf(track);
     tracks.splice(index, 1);
   }
   this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
}
```

Comment: Probably the issue is with referencing you have to make another reference and then splice or push the element in the temp array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a significant difference, because `includes()` will only return `true` if you pass it the actual instance (by that I mean a reference that points to the same object) of track that you are looking for.

The provided **solution** compares tracks only based on the track ID, so that is something different.

See the following example:

```js
const tracks = [
  {id: 1, title: "mysong1"},
  {id: 2, title: "mysong2"},
] 

function isTrackPresentIncludes(track){
  return tracks.includes(track);
}

function isTrackPresentFind(track){
  return tracks.find(it => it.id === track.id) !== undefined;
}


// this will be true
console.log("with includes(tracks[0]):\n", isTrackPresentIncludes(tracks[0]))
// this will be false as it's a different object
console.log("with includes({id: 1, title: \"mysong1\"}):\n", isTrackPresentIncludes({id: 1, title: "mysong1"}))

// this will be true
console.log("with find(tracks[0]):\n", isTrackPresentFind(tracks[0]))
// this will also be true
console.log("with find({id: 1, title: \"mysong1\"}):\n", isTrackPresentFind({id: 1, title: "mysong1"}))
```

You have the same issue with `indexOf()` in your `removeTrack()`.

There is another thing I don't particularly like about the solution. `find()` returns the track that was found but that return value is never actually used so to my mind you should use `some()` instead which just returns `true` or `false`.

I don't think this is a problem here but it could potentially lead to unexpected behavior if an array would hold *falsy* values.
Consider this:

```js
const arrayWithFalsyValues = [
  0,  // zero is falsy!
  1, 
  2, 
  3, 
  4, 
  5, 
  6, 
  7, 
  8
] 

function isPresent(toBeFound){
  if(arrayWithFalsyValues.find(number => number === toBeFound)){
    console.log(`Value ${toBeFound} found in array`);
  }
  else{
    console.log(`Value ${toBeFound} NOT found in array`);
  }
}

console.log("Array:", arrayWithFalsyValues)
// this will work as expected
console.log("Contains 3?")
isPresent(3)
console.log("Contains 8?")
isPresent(8)
console.log("Contains 10?")
isPresent(10)
// now search for the falsy value -> incorrect result
console.log("Contains 0?")
isPresent(0)
```

Comment: Your comments re includes() vs find() was the reason I thought my code could be a suitable alternative - I don't see anywhere that they use the return from find().  I will look at some() though - that sounds promising.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with referencing, You have make another reference of `playlistTracks`

```
addTrack(track) {
   let { playlistTracks } = this.state;
   let tracks = [...playlistTracks];
   if (!tracks.includes(track)) {
      tracks.push(track);
   }
   this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
}

removeTrack(track) {
   let { playlistTracks } = this.state;
   let tracks = [...playlistTracks];
   if (tracks.includes(track)) {
     let index = tracks.indexOf(track);
     tracks.splice(index, 1);
   }
   this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
}
```

## MY SUGGESTION

```
addTrack(track) {
   const { playlistTracks } = this.state;
   const tracks = [...playlistTracks];
   const index = tracks.indexOf(track);
   if (index < 0) {
      tracks.push(track);
   }
   this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
}

removeTrack(track) {
   const { playlistTracks } = this.state;
   const tracks = [...playlistTracks];
   const index = tracks.indexOf(track);
   if (index > -1) {
     tracks.splice(index, 1);
   }
   this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
}
```